# In a fragment, how to find a view defined in the activity's layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

In my **activity's layout**, I have a view which I'd want to access **from its attached fragment.**

How could I do it?

Normally, **from a fragment**, to find a view defined **in a fragment's layout** (so it's another use case), I just use the `inflater` to inflate the fragment's layout, and call `findVieById`.

But since my view is defined in the activity's layout, I can't do this.

**Could I use `getActivity().findViewById`?**

Comment: I think it's a bad architecture decision. You can implement necessary actions with this view directly in activity, implement the new interface and then call `((NewInterface) getActivity()).callMethod()`, or exclude this logic from fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my activity's layout, I have a view which **I'd want to** access from its attached fragment.

No, you don't want to.

> How could I do it?

`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.blah)`, but you shouldn't.

> But since my view is defined in the activity's layout, I can't do this.

Technically you can, you just shouldn't.

> Could I use getActivity().findViewById?

Yes, but you shouldn't.

---

As for the correct answer, this is why they created `Android Architecture Components: ViewModel / LiveData` - so that you wouldn't be tempted to access views directly. You could modify the data/state shared via ViewModel in one place, and thanks to LiveData all observers would be updated with it.

Therefore you never have to touch views directly, you just need to update data.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyViewModel myViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        myViewModel.myData().observe(this, (data) -> {
            if(data == null) return;

            updateViews(data);
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MyViewModel() {}

    private MutableLiveData<MyData> mutableData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<MyData> myData() {
        return mutableData;
    }

    public void updateData(MyData newData) {
        mutableData.postValue(newData);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyViewModel myViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);

        myViewModel.myData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (data) -> {
            if(data == null) return;

            updateViews(data);
        });
    }
}
```

This way:

- you don't need to mess with interfaces like it would say in [the official "fragment communication guide"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)
- you don't need to touch views directly, just touch data
- you keep up with [the best practices introduced in 2017](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#drive-ui-from-model) (see also [this video](https://youtu.be/FrteWKKVyzI?t=1099) and [this video](https://youtu.be/bEKNi1JOrNs?t=1653) from Google I/O 2017)

You can also find this technique in the official guides [**here**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#java).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice. You shouldn't do that. The Activity should handle its view on it own and you can trigger that handle function using an interface. Check this out.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).findViewById
```

or you can do `findViewById` for a view and make it global in your activity and can access it like:

```
((YourActivityName)getActivity()).viewName
```